# Replace import 'nodes/*.pp'?

Tags: puppet

For those of you who keep individual node files, what did you do (or what are you planning to do) to work around the elimination of the import command in puppet 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_import.html#what-to-use-instead) is quite clear on that:

1. Move your formerly imported `.pp` files into the same directory that holds `site.pp`
2. Use this directory as your `manifest` value in the master configuration

Comment: I didn't fully understand the documentation, but your wording made it much clearer. Thank you.